# Display Logo and Nav on same bar CSS

Tags: css

Sorry, proper newb here. I can't figure out how to display my title/logo and navigation on the same line in my css code. I want the title/logo to be on the left and the nav to be on the right. Please help me! A link to the work in progress http://saintdeiters.bigcartel.com

Here's my navigation CSS:

```
    #main_nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  }

#main_nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  }

#main_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }

#main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 17px 13px;
  border: 0;
  }

#mobile_nav {
  display: none;
  }
```

Here's my Site Header CSS:

```
#site_header header {
  margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

#site_header header #store_name {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 60px auto 78px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  }

#site_header header #store_name a { border: none; }

#site_header #branding {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  }

#site_header #branding a img {
  margin: left; 0 auto;
  }

#site_header #branding a h2 {
  display: none;
  }
```

Comment: @SaxonDuke...did my answer below help you? request you to respond if any of the answers here helped you

Comment: Yes indeed. You've all been very helpful and the issue has been resolved. Thank You! @AdityaSaxena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes to your css **without editing any HTML**:

```
#site_header #branding {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 0 20px;
}

#main_nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Screen capture on how this'll look:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `main_nav` inside the `header`.

```
<header>          
   <div id="branding">
      <a href="/">
       <h2>Home</h2>
       <img src="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/theme_images/5202027/max_h-1000+max_w-1000/saintd_LOGO.jpg" alt="Saint-Deiters">
      </a>
   </div>
   <nav id="main_nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li><li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="/cart">Cart</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Make the following changes in css

```
#main_nav {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}

#site_header #branding {
text-align: center;
padding: 3px 0 20px;
display: inline-block;   
}
```

> **`display: inline-block`** Element placed on the same line as adjacent content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can either float the `<ul>` and the `<img>` to the left, or set them both to `display:inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/HqWwL/

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to use a `<header>` and a `<nav>` together, you can achieve what you want using just either of them. ofcourse if you want to keep it that way, then it's otherwise.

You can see the `CSS` for my firebug editor for your `header` and `nav`. I have added a `width:500px` and a `float:right`.
[image]

You can of course add an extra padding to make it look more floating

```
  #site_header #branding {
    padding: 8px 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 196px;
}
```